# Proof of $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|a^n\|^{1/n} \le r(a)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-algebras, spectral-radius

Theorem $2.2.6$ in *Principles of Harmonic Analysis* by Anton Deitmar and Siegfried Echterhoff proves the well-known formula for the spectral radius in a unital Banach algebra, namely $r(a) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|a^n\|^{1/n}$. One of the steps involves proving $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|a^n\|^{1/n} \le r(a)$, about which I have some questions.

> To see that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|a^n\|^{1/n} \le r(a)$ recall $(\lambda 1 - a)^{-1} = \lambda^{-1}(1- \frac a\lambda)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}$ for $|\lambda| > \|a\|$, and hence, as the function is holomorphic there, the series converges
> in the norm-topology for every $|\lambda| > r(a)$ as we derive from Corollary B.6.7 applied to $z = \frac 1 \lambda$.

1. Why does the series converge in the norm topology for every $|\lambda| > r(a)$? I've stated Corollary B.6.7 below.

> For a fixed $|\lambda| > r(a)$ it follows that the sequence $a^n \frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}$ is bounded in $A$, so that there exists a constant $C \ge 0$ such that $\|a^n\| \le C|\lambda|^{n+1}$ for every $n\in \Bbb N$. Taking $n$th roots on both sides and then applying $\limsup$ shows that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|a^n\|^{1/n} \le |\lambda|$. Since this holds for every $|\lambda| > r(a)$, we get $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|a^n\|^{1/n} \le r(a)$.

2. Why is the sequence $\left\{a^n \frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}\right\}$ bounded in $A$?

Thanks!

---

*Corollary B.6.7:*

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: $2.$ The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \|a^n\|\lambda|^{-(n+1)}$ is convergent. Therefore the sequence $\|a^n\|\,|\lambda|^{-(n+1)}$ tends to $0.$ Hence this sequence is bounded. $1.$ The function $(\lambda I-a)^{-1}$ is holomorphic for $|\lambda|>r(a)$ therefore it is represented by the convergent  Laurent series for $|\lambda|>r(a).$  For $|\lambda|>\|a\|$ the Laurent series is equal $\sum a^n\lambda^{-n-1}$. Therefore this series is convergent for $|\lambda|>r(a).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc For $(1)$, I don't understand the last part of your reasoning. The Laurent series equals $\sum a^n \lambda^{-n-1}$ for $|\lambda| > \|a\|$. Also, $\|a\| \ge r(a)$. How does this tell us that $\sum a^n \lambda^{-n-1}$ converges for every $|\lambda| > r(a)$?

Comment: The Laurent series of $(\lambda I-a)^{-1}$ is convergent in the annulus contained in the domain of holomorphy, i.e. for $|\lambda|>r(a).$ For $|\lambda|>\|a\|$ the Laurent series is equal $\sum a^n\lambda^{-n-1}.$ The Laurent series is unique. Therefore $\sum a^n\lambda^{-n-1}$ is the Laurent series also in the domain $|\lambda|>r(a).$

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!